# Prevent type annotation from type widening a const expression

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to keep a literal expression constant (via const assertion), but still type check it against a type to guard against missing/excess properties?

In other words, how prevent the type annotation from overriding the `as const` assertion, widening the type?

I understand what's happening more or less, and I've already asked around on chat, so I'm pretty sure this doesn't have a solution (in type land), but maybe there's a hack I don't know about.

Use case:

I need to define a config from which I can conditionally infer types based on the values, but at the same time I want to ensure that config contains exactly the same keys as a type it's based off of.

Here's a minimal example. The `State` type is the blueprint for the keys, and the `config` object should type check against those keys. But, I also need the `config` to be a constant so that I can drill down into it and get unit union type, not a widened `string` type.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oCULwCYHsB2ANiADwDeAUFFVPAFxR4CuAtgEYQBOA3Jda-QGdgHAJZ4A5jwC+APh7kAxviFQleAGYjx9DEo5ZiAawggc62AiQAaKKSgA3eAUYRBwseKiyoqCtRr0do7OrlAARPCRYV5WvFT8tg5OLvRhrOnRUuRSNAKqysDyoJBQxiB5qAAUxRBm+RpaAJQA2mV1NXVqmuIAus1hwS5hPVxQAPRjUACSUADu8HjAUMAAFiJ5wDhQ7OGR8NEAPuHprGHk50A)

```
type State = Readonly<{
    a: number;
    b: string;
}>;

const config: Record<keyof State, { value: string }> = {
    a: { value: "aaa" },
    b: { value: "bbb" }
} as const;

// I want this to be "aaa" | "bbb"
type ConfigValues = (typeof config)[keyof typeof config]["value"];
```

I can do this:

```
const config = {
    a: { value: "aaa" },
    b: { value: "bbb" }
} as const;

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
const config_check: Record<keyof State, any> = config;
```

But the above will only check missing props, not excess props :/.

Note that this is a simple example. In real world the config is more complex and the type I want to infer is conditional based on the values.

Also, I've bumped into this problem pattern several times already, so it doesn't seem like an edge case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generic helper function to constraint a type, while keeping it narrow for inference:

```
function createConfig<P extends string, T extends Record<keyof State, { value: P }>>(
    cfg: { [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof State ? T[K] : never }) {
    return cfg
}
```

```
const config = createConfig({
    a: { value: "aaa" },
    b: { value: "bbb" },
    c: { value: "ccc" } // conditional type error akin to excess property check
})

type keys = (typeof config)[keyof typeof config]["value"]; // "aaa" | "bbb"
type keyA = (typeof config)["a"]["value"] // "aaa"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=51&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oCULwCYHsB2ANiADwDeAUFFVPAFxR4CuAtgEYQBOA3Jda-QGdgHAJZ4A5jwC+APh7kAZozwBjYCPxQVHTEgDC+BSPHEAClAgAPJHiwCoQ0RIA0UACoXrEW-YwqcHFjEANYQIDgKsAhIrqRQAG7wBIwQ9OayMgAUvFQqCuL0cQDaANJQYlCh4ZFuALr0ZVY2dpVhEVGI0AD87qW1UPR4EPGcUFIAlFAU1FA6wIwceFr55FLk5P54QlqGxlCo2roQBnhG4pnT1HRTCUkp9ABE8M8PY845UPw3icmpUA+sQGvKTvGYqQq3X6PFQw4FQAD08J2thE6nwSSgoEgFg4HACNGCFWAOE8KggAnsYDxkA4oC0AAsICpgqtxussdAqvZUJkOe1NmdxkUqu0+ZEBcZakUHj8Ug9alwEUini8oAAff6A1gPcgc1ogACC+ygvPAEH5u3EQqe8ulsog8qV-2e8AeQA)

Comment: Not gonna work because the inferred type of `value` is a union of all possible values, not a literal value. You can check this by doing `(typeof config)["a"]["value"];` which resolves to `"aaa" | "bbb"` instead of `"aaa"`. In other words, the return value type isn't a constant literal type, but the type of the `cfg` parameter annotation, which means we're back at my original issue. This means I won't be able to infer conditional type based on actual values in the literal object.

That's why I noted my example was simplified.

Comment: Very cool, thanks! The `P` param seems extra, though. Now what remains is adding support for [partial type params](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242#issuecomment-411867079) so that we can easily pass the type for `State` instead of hardcoding it. The only way to do it now seems to be to factor the config into a var, and do `createConfig<State, typeof cfg>(cfg)`. But that's a separate issue.

Comment: Yeah, or you could curry the function: `createConfig<State>()(cfg)`, where the first function part potentially can take some default state. By the way:  `P` is intentional. Otherwise TS infers `string` instead of the passed-in string literal types (that's the way the compiler works). This is a neat trick, if you don't want to use `as const` from the caller side.

Comment: Oh, nice. I did use `as const` still, so that's why I missed it :). Good point about currying!